# PHP Session Variable Not Working After Page Redirect

Tags: php, session, iis

I know this question has been asked several times, but none of the other SO posts seem to have any answers that can help me.

I have been having issues with a site that I am building and I have not been able to save session variables. I finally decided to just put up two simple php pages...one called getsession.php and another called setsession.php.  The files are barebones, and look like the following:

**setsession.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['loggedinusername'] = "SomeName";
   header('Location: getsession.php');
   exit();
?>
```

**getsession.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo "The Set Variable is: ".$_SESSION['loggedinusername'];
?>
```

As you can see, setsession.php just sets a session variable, and then redirects to getsession.php and attempts to retreive the value.

Unfortunately, All session variables are lost after redirect. The output I get is

> Notice: Undefined index: loggedinusername in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyTest\getsession.php on line 3 The Set Variable
>   is:

I am using IIS and PHP 7.0.  I have checked the log, and the above error message is the only thing that appears there. Also, my PHP.INI File has the following settings under sessions:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 720
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have access to php.ini ?

Comment: I do have access to php.ini.  I have also given full access to the directory that the session files are being written to just to see if that would help.

Comment: Check if register_globals is off in php.ini

Comment: I don't even have a register_globals setting in my php.ini.

Comment: Do you use HTTPS in your browser during testing?

Comment: I am not using HTTPS in my browser for testing.  I will be using HTTPS before I deploy to production.

Comment: Refer this link to turn it off or emulate it as off. http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.misc.php#faq.misc.registerglobals

Comment: @AmbrishPathak  I got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are testing on your local PC and unlikely to have SSL set up. And you have `session.cookie_secure` enabled.

> **session.cookie_secure** boolean
>
> session.cookie_secure specifies whether
>   cookies should only be sent over secure connections. Defaults to off.

If you're using HTTP, your browser will receive cookies from the server but it will never send them back on an unsecured (non-HTTPS) connection. That's why you don't have a session.

Comment: Perfect!  I was starting to go insane.